# Unable to install OCaml on macOS Mac M1

Tags: macos, ocaml, apple-m1, merlin, dune

I had installed merlin 6 months ago to be able to compile Ocaml and I had no problems. I have recently upgraded to update everything but it was impossible to make the package work.

When I try to reinstall it I get this error message (opam install -y merlin):

```
[coq-released] synchronised from https://coq.inria.fr/opam/released
[default] no changes from https://opam.ocaml.org
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗ install ocaml-base-compiler 4.12.0  [required by ocaml]
  ∗ install ocaml-config        2       [required by ocaml]
  ∗ install ocaml               4.12.0  [required by merlin]
  ∗ install ocamlfind           1.9.3   [required by dot-merlin-reader]
  ∗ install dune                2.9.3   [required by merlin]
  ∗ install result              1.5     [required by merlin]
  ∗ install easy-format         1.3.2   [required by yojson]
  ∗ install csexp               1.5.1   [required by merlin]
  ∗ install cppo                1.6.8   [required by yojson]
  ∗ install biniou              1.2.1   [required by yojson]
  ∗ install yojson              1.7.0   [required by merlin]
  ∗ install dot-merlin-reader   4.1     [required by merlin]
  ∗ install merlin              4.4-412
===== ∗ 13 =====

<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>   
⬇ retrieved biniou.1.2.1  (cached)
⬇ retrieved csexp.1.5.1  (cached)
⬇ retrieved dot-merlin-reader.4.1  (cached)
⬇ retrieved cppo.1.6.8  (cached)
⬇ retrieved easy-format.1.3.2  (cached)
⬇ retrieved dune.2.9.3  (cached)
⬇ retrieved ocaml-base-compiler.4.12.0  (cached)
⬇ retrieved result.1.5  (cached)
⬇ retrieved ocamlfind.1.9.3  (cached)
⬇ retrieved yojson.1.7.0  (cached)
⬇ retrieved merlin.4.4-412  (cached)
[ERROR] The installation of ocaml-base-compiler failed at "make install".

#=== ERROR while installing ocaml-base-compiler.4.12.0 ========================#
# context     2.1.2 | macos/arm64 |  | https://opam.ocaml.org#71d8d30e
# path        ~/.opam/4.12.0/.opam-switch/build/ocaml-base-compiler.4.12.0
# command     ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh install make install
# exit-code   2
# env-file    ~/.opam/log/ocaml-base-compiler-11755-86d59b.env
# output-file ~/.opam/log/ocaml-base-compiler-11755-86d59b.out
### output ###
# if test -f ocamlnat ; then \
# [...]
#        "/Users/theosouchon/.opam/4.12.0/lib/ocaml"; \
#     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 \
#        toplevel/opttopstart.cmx toplevel/opttopstart.o \
#        "/Users/theosouchon/.opam/4.12.0/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs"; \
#   fi
# cd "/Users/theosouchon/.opam/4.12.0/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs" && \
#      ranlib ocamlcommon.a ocamlbytecomp.a ocamloptcomp.a
# ranlib: error: exactly one archive should be specified
# make[2]: *** [installoptopt] Error 1
# make[1]: *** [installopt] Error 2
# make: *** [install] Error 2
```

If you ever have an idea to solve this problem I'm interested

Thank you very much,
Theo Souchon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that you have has nothing to do with merlin per se. The problem is that you can't build the compiler using the llvm toolchain, which is used by default on your machine.

The GNU version of the `ranlib` tool is able to take several archive arguments, unlike the llvm version of `ranlib` that fails on more than one archive.

The general answer is that you should install and select the GNU toolchain in order to build OCaml. I would start my investigation with running `which ranlib` to understand why you have the broken `ranlib` in the PATH. It could also be possible that you used `brew` to install the llvm toolchain, then use `brew unlink` to undo this. In the end, you want `ranlib` in your path that for `ranlib --version` prints `GNU ranlib`, not `LLVM`.

Also, in macOS, there's the tool called `xcode-select` that lets you install and select the toolchains. I don't have the latest version of macOS available, so I can't be sure, but you can try to run `xcode-select --install` to install the toolchain and use `xcode-select --switch` to select an appropriate one.

With all that said, the [OCaml](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/issues) and [opam](https://github.com/ocaml/opam/issues) issue trackers are much better places to resolve such problems than SO.

Comment: Hello,
I have this :
`theosouchon@MacBook-Pro-de-Theo ~ % which ranlib
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/ranlib`

I think you're right because I'm trying to install something else at the same time but I don't know how to switch environment and I can't find the previous one... do you have a way to do it? I can also submit my problem on the place you advised me.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem. Just switch the clang I had downloaded via homebrew (llvm) to the basic one available on Mac.